# Xlwings won't close book after saving

Tags: python, xlwings

I am currently trying to use xlwings to open a book and update it's links, then save and close. The relevant code I am using is:

```
import os
import xlwings as xw

app=xw.App(add_book=False)
app.display_alerts=False

for file in os.scandir(dirname):
         if (file.name.endswith("Unposted Summary.xlsm")):
                path=file.path
                tmp=app.books.api.Open(path,UpdateLinks=True)
                tmp.save(path)
                app.quit()
```

After having read the documentation several times and using several different methods such as app.quit(), app.kill(), book.close(), etc... I have been unable to get xlwings to close the current book after saving it, so I haven't even approached the question of whether the links are updating properly or not.

I'm guessing the problem is coming from how I'm opening the books. If so, I don't know the syntax to close them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually use `xlwings`, but from what I understand `app.books.api.Open` calls and returns the COM object, from where I don't even think `tmp.save(...)` would work (at least not in my case).

A better option would be work directly with `xw.Book` wrapper instead without the `api` call:

```
for file in os.scandir(dirname):
     if (file.name.endswith("Unposted Summary.xlsm")):
        tmp=app.books.open(file.path, update_links=True)
        tmp.save()
        tmp.close()
```

I would also advise you to exercise `os.path.abspath` and keep in mind your working directory while looping though `dirname`.

Comment: When I try the syntax you've suggested above, it throws an exception:

"__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_links'"

Comment: Odd, I thought it uses the same `kwarg` as `xw.Book`.  Try `xw.Book(file.path, update_links=True)` then?

Comment: Yeah I'm not getting that error.  Which `xlwings` and python version are you using? My `xlwings` is `0.16.2` and python `3.7.4`.

Comment: Mine's older, but it looks like the syntax hasn't changed since xlwings 0.9.0.

I'll try updating it anyway, but that runs me into trouble with the corporate firewall... I'll be back in a few hours...

Comment: If your corporate firewall is anything like mine (proxy server, blocking the SSL validation), You can add a global config `pip.ini` for your pip with `trusted-host` for `pypi.python.org` and etc.  Dig around Google with these keywords hopefully it helps you.  If not I can loop back when I'm a bit more freed up.

Comment: Updating to the newest version of Python & Xlwings made the above syntax work perfectly!  Accepting the above as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the version when support for these keywords were added in the docs. Will see that I can fix this. This was with 0.16.1: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-16-1-dec-1-2019